# How can I know when AJAX loaded content finish the images loading?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, loading

I'm loading HTML from an AJAX request, and some `img` tags in it.

I need to know when the images loaded in the AJAX are fully loaded to resize the container.
I don't know how many images are in the result, so I can't simply check the `.complete` value.

Do you know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, the `$(window).load()` command can set up a function to be called once all the images are loaded, as follows:

```
$(window).load(
    function() {
        // weave your magic here.
    }
);
```

If you're not using jQuery, I'd just do what I've done when I want a *little* bit of its functionality: download it and examine the source to see how it does it. Then do that :-)

Comment: Well, the ajax loads the images when the user requests it. So it's a lot after that the content load.
Is possible to use the .load() function in any element? maybe I could hook that event to the container.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHTTPrequests` have properties that you can use to determine when the load has completed. If you are using JavaScript directly, you would need to assign a function to the `onreadystatechange` event. This is called each time that the state changes. The states are stored in `ReadyState` and are:

0. Uninitiated
1. Loading
2. Loaded
3. Interactive
4. Complete

In your function, you check that the status is 4 and call the other required functions.

jQuery has events that tell you when certain things have occurred. [View the AJAX Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

Comment: Yes, but there's no event for when the images of the resultant ajax request are loaded.
The .load() is the solution.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Pax, I've found the solution.

On the **success** event of the ajax request (using jQuery), I've added the following code:

```
$('img', this).load(function() {
    resize_element(this);
});
```

Thanks both of you!